# yyyymmddHHMMSS convert to yyyy-mm-ss HH:MM:SS

Tags: r, date, datetime, time

In R:
How can I change the column of a data frame from yyyymmddHHMMSS to yyyy-mm-ss HH:MM:SS?

I tried

```
for(i in 1:nrow(tabla_eaq)){
  tabla_eaq[i,'datetime'] = ymd_hms(tabla_eaq[i,'datetime'])
}
```

But it shows up as for example 1606514222 for input 20201127215702.

Answer (score 0):

We don't need a `for` loop as the `ymd_hms` is vectorized

```
library(lubridate)
tabla_eaq$datetime <- ymd_hms(tabla_eaq$datetime)
```

#### data

```
tabla_eaq <- data.frame(datetime = c(20201127215702, 20201127215702, 20201127215702))
```